# css issue when zooming in on the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns in css aligned beside each other. I don't understand why when I zoom into the browser the UI becomes responsive? For example when I zoom in the browser, `<p>helooooo<p/>` will enlarge only in respect to the column. On zooming in notice how the columns remain at their specified width? why does that happen? shouldn't the columns also expand in respect to the text?

```css
body, html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.col1{
  min-width:30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: gray;
  float:left;
}

.col2{
  min-width:40%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;

}

.col3{
  min-width:30%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: red;
  float:left
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="col1">
    <p>heloooooooooooooo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
      <p>heloooooooooooooo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
      <p>heloooooooooooooo</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show any change when zooming in or out. But anyway, when the browser zooms, it's essentially changing the width of the viewport.. so if you have media queries, they will come into play.

Answer (score 0):

This because you have set the column lengths to  a specific value.

```
min-width:40%;
height:100%;
```

So whether you zoom or not, it will be of the same percentage. meaning it wont be zoomed.

Comment: how can I re create what I did in css but with the zoom effect? I want the col's to be specified though, which is by pixels won't work right?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap, use the grid system.

<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4></div><div class="col-md-4></div><div class="col-md-4></div></div>

would get you three columns with the zoom effect

Comment: the cols still stay at a fixed percentage when zooming in

Comment: remove the percentage and get a pixel value, that should do.